# Assigning __call__ variable vs. defining __call__ in class definition

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

I was investigating the PyTorch codebase, and came across an interesting quirk regarding how they implemented the `__call__` method for the [`Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/71b00a049adbc76d1c760a6220ef13cae9a9f4ed/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L204) class, which is in `torch.nn`. It is an important class as it is the base class for all neural network modules.

Two points of clarification:
i) I understand what `__call__` does in general. It allows you to call an instance of a class as if it were a function. The question is about the manner in which the method is defined in the example below.
ii) although I make reference to an example from PyTorch, I am asking this as a general question about implementing classes in Python

The skeleton of the class is as follows

```py
class Module:
    ...
    def _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs):
        ...

    __call__ = _call_impl
```

My question is, why assign the `__call__` method in this way? Why not do this

```py
class Module:
    ...
    def __call__(self, *input, **kwargs):
        # all the code originally in _call_impl
        ...
```

Is there a difference between these two ways of creating the `__call__` method? If so, what is that difference?

(`_call_impl` is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/71b00a049adbc76d1c760a6220ef13cae9a9f4ed/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1125), and the assignment to `__call__` happens just afterwards, at this [line](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/71b00a049adbc76d1c760a6220ef13cae9a9f4ed/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1177))

Comment: No, except for the fact that `_cal_impl` has two different references in the class namespace. But in general, a `def foo(): ...` is equivalent to `foo = function()` where `function` is the function class (you *can* actually use that constructor, but that is for very advanced use-cases)

Comment: Because of [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/74746).